# How to use QUERY and IMPORTRANGE function together to extract and transpose data in google sheet?

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have 3 range of data (`F8:G23`,`F31:G46`,`F54:G69`) in one google sheet as shown above, I want to export this 3 range of data into another google sheet by using `IMPORTRANGE`. At the same time, I want to transpose the data and remove the blank cell between 3 range of data (`F24:G30`,`F47:G53`). This is the formula that I had tried:

```
transpose(Query({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DD9qniGyi9QSE9TYw-EnH-3Cug--BwqyViPW2nrrPLM/edit", "Sheet1!F8:G133")},"select * where Col1 is not null"))
```

The screenshot below is the expected output after using the formula above:

[image]

However, what I get from the formula is not what I expected. All letter had gone and the range size is 2 rows x 25 columns instead of 6 rows x 11 columns. Besides, the `S` and `B` also attached to the name `Group 1` and `Group 2`. I attached a screenshot below to show what I got from the formula above:

[image]

What should I do to my formula so that I can get the expected output? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TO_TEXT({
 IMPORTRANGE("1DD9qniGyi9QSE9TYw-EnH-3Cug--BwqyViPW2nrrPLM", "Sheet1!F8:G23"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1DD9qniGyi9QSE9TYw-EnH-3Cug--BwqyViPW2nrrPLM", "Sheet1!F31:G46"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1DD9qniGyi9QSE9TYw-EnH-3Cug--BwqyViPW2nrrPLM", "Sheet1!F54:G69")}),
 "where Col1 is not null", )))
```